# How redirect param sort in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, sorting, redirect

I would like to do in htaccess redirect pages with parameter sort subpage without her.

That is: 
www.domain.com/XYZ?sort=1&metoda=2 -> www.domain.com/XYZ

Currently I have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} "sort =" [NC]
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} "metoda =" [NC]
RewriteRule (. *) / 1 $? [R = 301, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sort=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} (^|&)metoda=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ $0? [R=302,L]
```